# Batch Script to ZIP Together Files With Same Names

Tags: batch, script, automation, zip, archiving

I have 314 vector images I'm looking to submit to the various stock image sites I'm a contributor to, but a number of these require that the vectors be bundled into a ZIP folder with a JPEG preview image with the same name. How might I go about creating a .bat that zips all the files within a directory together based on having the same file name?

I typically use 7-Zip, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

If using the command-line version of 7-Zip, this will use the zip format for all files in "yourDir" using max compression for any file with "samename" in the file name, regardless of extension. The compression level "-mx9" is optional.

```
7za a -tzip "archivename.zip" "C:\yourDir\samename*.*" -mx9
```